# Use local storage value in script src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I have my Local Storage value inside the SRC value of a script tag?

I have this:

```
<script id="gmap" async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=">
```

And I `get` the local value:

```
var gkey = localStorage.getItem('LSGMD-GoogleMapsAPIKey');
```

The local value is set and when showing it via an alert it shows up correctly. But now how can I use this local value in the script. It should become:

```
<script id="gmap" async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=LOCALVALUE">
```

EDIT ONE: This is what I tried but while it does change the SRC it won't show the map.

```
<script>
  (function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var gkey = localStorage.getItem('LSGMD-GoogleMapsAPIKey');
      var glink = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=";
      var gscript = glink + gkey;
      $("#gmap").attr("src",gscript);
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

How could I add a var to this part `&key=VARHERE">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one solution would be to create that script element dynamically

```
<script>
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = function () {
        var ipServer = location.host;
    };
    var gkey = localStorage.getItem('LSGMD-GoogleMapsAPIKey');

    script.setAttribute( 'src', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=' + gkey);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should remove the original script with id gmap correct.

Comment: you can include every attribute there on the snippet from the answer, and yes you should remove original script

Comment: I am going to continue in the block of code and then I will see which one works out best for me and accept the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve that value from local storage and dynamically append a script tag to the document.

```
<script>
   var gkey = localStorage.getItem('LSGMD-GoogleMapsAPIKey');
   var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
   scriptTag.src = 'https://......' + '?queryparams....&key=' + gkey;
   document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
</script>
```

Comment: I could be wrong but is this not the same things as I did in Jquery only now in plain Javascript? No sorry! My mistake... I looked to quickly it has it's differences.

Comment: I just tested it and this works just as good as the previous answer! Thank you very much! I am going to continue in the block of code and then I will see which one works out best for me and accept the answer accordingly.